# Can I use thread.h from C11 in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c11

I don't want to use C++11 `std::thread` because of exceptions. Is it possible to use C11's [threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) from C++ (for some version)?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. If you disable Exception you wont  get any. Also why do you explicitly want no exceptions?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483425/mixing-c11-stdthread-and-c-system-threads-ie-pthreads (especially the answer from Jens Gustedt)

Comment: Could you be more specific than "because of exceptions"? What's your issue with them in this context?

Comment: The code base I'm working with has exceptions disabled, so I can't check if the thread creation has failed

Comment: @nielsen Thanks for the link! According to that, I should be able to use C11's thread library from C++11. But I'm not sure if I can trust that answer since it doesn't provide any source I can verify. Besides, I know C++11 was supported in MSVC17 but C11 wasn't supported until MSVC2019.

Comment: [std::thread without exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14162287/995714)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex